# Web driver skips special characters - "(" and "&" characters when using sendkeys

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

As part of my automated tests, I need to type a string with special characters ("(PT books)") into a text box on a web application.

When I run the test, `"("` is always skipped. There is no issue with `")"`. I started investigating it and tried all special characters that require a `shift key` to be pressed `("~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?")` and found that it always skipped `"("`  and `"&"`. I also tried the same test on the Google search box and in this case all characters were displayed.

I am using Selenium Web driver(2.25.0) + Java + Firefox(15.0.1). I also have `setEnableNativeEvents` to false in my firefox profile.

I also tried this using Internet Explorer and it works fine. I would like to stick to firefox as most of my tests run on firefox.

Any ideas as to why `"("` and `"&"` are not displayed on the web application I am testing?

Here is the code that I am using

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setEnableNativeEvents( false);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

String searchTerm = "~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?" ;

String Link = "http://" ;

driver.get( "http://www.google.com");
driver.findElement(By. id("gbqfq")).sendKeys(searchTerm);

driver.get(Link);
driver.findElement(By. id("ctl00_ctl00_FindField_FindField_ctl00_findFieldLinks_basic")).click();
driver.findElement(By. id(UIMapping.SearchBoxId)).sendKeys(searchTerm);
```

Comment: Its just a hunch - but have you tried encoding them with the URLEncoder ?

Comment: I tried URLEncoder and Decoder and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. I have a simple workaround for this, which is not the kind of solution i am looking for but time being this helps. If there is a better way to handle please suggest.

```
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        String searchKey = "TShirt(M)";
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://mywebsite.com/");

        if (searchKey.Contains("(") || searchKey.Contains("&"))
        {
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value ='" + searchKey + "';", driver.FindElement(By.Id("search_text"))); 
        }
        else
        {
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("search_text")).SendKeys(searchKey);
        }

        driver.FindElement(By.Id("search_button")).Click();
```