# Few charecters are omitted while using selenium SendKeys() function in firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

few charecters are omitted while using selenium SendKeys() function in firefox

```
WebElement name = driver.findElement(localizator);
name.clear();
name.sendKeys("New-!NotVerified123456123456");
```

but in the application its inputing NNotVerified123456123456, its ommitting ew-! from the sequence

Browser used is firefoc 31.4

Comment: Try storing `"New-!NotVerified123456123456"` in a string and do `name.sendKeys(str);`. Else you can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603210/web-driver-skips-special-characters-and-characters-when-using-sendkeys) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875416/how-do-i-send-special-characters-via-sendkeys)

Comment: by using javascript executor , issue got resolved